# How to find whether PDF has landscape orientation or portrait

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext, pdfbox

Are there tools to determine whether a PDF has landscape orientation or portrait?

I have currently looked upon **pdfbox** and **Itext** for this but seem that I could not find it.  Please tell if they support this.

Extracting the PDF pages information using **Origami** is providing a information the pdf pages have rotation of some degree. Here is what Origami reports:

```
{:Parent=>#<PDF::Reader::Reference:0x872349c @id=8, @gen=0>, :Type=>:Page, 
 :Contents=>#<PDF::Reader::Reference:0x8722f24 @id=4, @gen=0>, :Resources=># <PDF::Reader::Reference:0x870dbd8 @id=2, @gen=0>, 
:MediaBox=>[0, 0, 612, 792], :Rotate=>270}
```

**Rotate : 270**

What does the 'rotation' actually mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `pdfinfo` commandline utility has a way to let you see the page size info and MediaBox, CropBox, BleedBox, ArtBox and TrimBox values for each and every page. Here I ask about the values for pages 2 to 4 of a specific document:

```
pdfinfo -box -f 2 -l 4 sample.pdf
  Creator:        FrameMaker 6.0
  Producer:       Acrobat Distiller 5.0.5 (Windows)
  CreationDate:   Thu Aug 17 16:43:06 2006
  ModDate:        Tue Aug 22 12:20:24 2006
  Tagged:         no
  Form:           AcroForm
  Pages:          146
  Encrypted:      no
  Page    2 size: 419.535 x 297.644 pts
  Page    2 rot:  90
  Page    3 size: 297.646 x 419.524 pts
  Page    3 rot:  0
  Page    4 size: 297.646 x 419.524 pts
  Page    4 rot:  0
  Page    2 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
  Page    2 CropBox:     87.25   430.36   506.79   728.00
  Page    2 BleedBox:    87.25   430.36   506.79   728.00
  Page    2 TrimBox:     87.25   430.36   506.79   728.00
  Page    2 ArtBox:      87.25   430.36   506.79   728.00
  Page    3 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
  Page    3 CropBox:    148.17   210.76   445.81   630.28
  Page    3 BleedBox:   148.17   210.76   445.81   630.28
  Page    3 TrimBox:    148.17   210.76   445.81   630.28
  Page    3 ArtBox:     148.17   210.76   445.81   630.28
  Page    4 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
  Page    4 CropBox:    148.17   210.76   445.81   630.28
  Page    4 BleedBox:   148.17   210.76   445.81   630.28
  Page    4 TrimBox:    148.17   210.76   445.81   630.28
  Page    4 ArtBox:     148.17   210.76   445.81   630.28
  Page    4 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
  File size:      6888764 bytes
  Optimized:      yes
  PDF version:    1.4
```

Note the following:

- `*Box` values: these are 4 numbers whose units are PostScript points: the first pair represents the coordinates of the lower left corner, the second pair represents coordinates of the upper right corner.
- `MediaBox`: Is a *required* setting for each page inside the PDF.
- `TrimBox`: Is an *optional* setting and defaults to the same as MediaBox if it is not explicitly defined. If it deviates from the MediaBox, then it tells PDF viewers (and printer drivers) to only render and display that particular part of the full page.
- `Page size`: This info is derived + computed from the distances that are set up by the TrimBox value.
- `rot`: This gives the value of the page rotation. May be `0`, `90`, `180` or `270` degrees.

Now, the page's *landscape* and *portrait* definitions are this:

- It is regarded as 'landscape' if the width is greater than the height.
- It is regarded as 'portrait' if the height is greater than the width.
- It is undetermined if width and height have the same value.

**But!**,....

- ...you can put a non-zero `/Rotation` value into your PDF source code (which `pdfinfo` will show as `rot:` info) and achieve this way that a 'portrait' PDF page will display as 'landscape' and vice-versa;
- ...you could define a 'landscape' shaped TrimBox inside a 'portrait' shaped MediaBox or vice versa, as well as mix it with a non-zero rotation, and achieve this way that the 'landscape' shaped content will appear in 'portrait' (or upside-down) look...

Confused about this? Don't worry, many are. Fact is, 'landscape' and 'portrait' aren't clearly and un-ambiguously defined technical terms. They are just conventions to describe what we see...

Comment: Wow that was quite informative. Trim Box would as same as   Media Box . if a trim box is set it would display as only the that particular section this is was not aware

Comment: Just one thing the angle of rotation with non-zero will always convert the portrait view to landspace and vice versa or does the value matter . Meaning does the 270 would convert the portrait to landscape but not 180  would just show the content in a normal way but in reverse order is that correct

Comment: @user1438735: `/Rotation 180` results in upside down orientation. `/Rotation 90` is clockwise by 90 degrees. `/Rotation 270` is clockwise by 270 degrees (the same as counterclockwise by 90 degrees).

Comment: sorry about that I just did it. so Rotation 270 and rotation 90 would display the portrait pdf as landscape and vice-versa is that correct

Comment: @user1438735: that's correct (but be aware that if you compare the 2 'landscapes', one is upside down as compared to the other...