# PHP getimagesize of PDF -> Blob

Tags: php, oracle, pdf, getimagesize

I am trying to achieve the ability to add PDF uploads to an existing image upload function I've inherited. I've noticed that I'm not able to use getimagesize on PDFs. Is there a way to determine the dimensions of a PDF using PHP? - Or - Would it be better to hardcode the dimensions when uploading PDFs.

Comment: Is converting the PDF to an JPEG, then getting the size of the image out of the question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227014/convert-pdf-to-jpeg-with-php-and-imagemagick

Comment: @EricLeschinski If at all possible I want to keep them PDFs, but I'm not opposed to using a plugin to find the size.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

The pdfinfo.exe (part of the XPDF tools) has the parameters to specify which page, or all pages to get the dimensions.

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec("pdfinfo ".$your_pdf_file_or_url);

    // find page count
    preg_match('/Pages:\s+([0-9]+)/', $output, $pagecountmatches);
    $pagecount = $pagecountmatches[1];

    // find page sizes
    preg_match('/Page size:\s+([0-9]{0,5}\.?[0-9]{0,3}) x ([0-9]{0,5}\.?[0-9]{0,3})/', 
         $output, $pagesizematches);
    $width = round($pagesizematches[1]/2.83);
    $height = round($pagesizematches[2]/2.83);

    echo "pagecount = $pagecount <br>width = $width<br>height = $height";

?>
```

http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html

[Get the layout mode (landscape or portrait) of a pdf from php/linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467494/get-the-layout-mode-landscape-or-portrait-of-a-pdf-from-php-linux)

[PHP Get height and width in Pdf file proprieties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622357/php-get-height-and-width-in-pdf-file-proprieties)

**Option 2**

If you are on a linux server with Image Magick installed:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('identify -format "%wx%h" ' . $path_to_pdf) . '[0]';
$geometry = `$command`;
list($width, $height) = split("x", $geometry);
```

Then you can access the dimensions through $width and $height.

http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/134081-find-out-width-and-height-of-a-given-pdf-file/

Comment: That's kinda where I landed on this, I was just hoping for a more 'built-in' way to do this.